# How to write a counter for a .txt file in java

Tags: java

I have a program that I am writing and I have it completed but I keep receiving an error in a counter that I am using.  The purpose of the program is to build a plate stacker and I have finished that but need to write a counter based on the particular colors used (how many green plates...etc.).  As I know several classmates use this site to cheat, I will not post the code in whole but only the fragments I feel are necessary.  Below is an example of a statement that I am using to attempt to get a count of the beige plates in the text file.  The statement is in a while loop with the other colors having the same coding.  I also have initialized the counter (int beige = 0;) prior to this and outside of the while loop:

```
        if(line == "beige")
        {
            beige++;
        }
```

I have a System.out following these statements to display the count but it always comes up as 0 so I believe the problem is in this particular fragment.  If I need to send additional coding I will but I believe it is something to do with this or the placement of it in the while loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are comparing the string in a wrong way. Use `.equals` method.

```
if (line.equals("beige"))
    beige++;
```

Second, you can use HashMap for this kind of problem where you keep updating the value(count) for key(color) and it will save you a lot of if conditions if say there are a hundred different colors!

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it and it counts them right now!  I will try the HashMap out as well!